# How to use Stylesheet.create in a class component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to use React Native's Stylesheet.create method in class component and I'm getting an error. This does work in functional components but not in class components. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the StyleSheet outside of the component.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

class NewComponent extends React. Component {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {

render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

    </View>
  )
}
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```